# How to enable content security policy to selective http patterns in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, content-security-policy, spring-security-ldap

My spring security config looks like:

```
<http pattern="/*/yyy/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/*/zzz/**" security="none"/>


<http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">
    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/*/api/products" access="xxxx" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
</http>
```

Now, for the http pattern with security="none" above, I want to enable Content Security Policy (CSP) for that. As long as I keep it security="none", I don't think I can apply CSP to it.

the header to enable CSP in spring security is like:

```
<headers>
    <header name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'"/>
</headers>
```

Now, I want to apply this header only to the first two http patterns where I have security="none" right now and not to the rest of the URLS I have added in the next http block. I just could not find a way to do it. Is it possible? Can someone please suggest?

I don't need to define entry-point-ref to these first two patterns. But, removing security="none" kind of forces me to define one for it. Please note that all I want is to be able to enable CSP for those selected patterns and that is all. Please help!

**Update:**

Answer (score 3):

Using `security="none"` means that security is not applied to the URLs, so the statement of adding a Content Security Policy with Spring Security to URLs mapped with `security="none"` is contradictory.

I'm guessing that you want to allow any user access to those URLs. If that is the case, you can easily use the `permitAll` expression.

Then, you can specify which URLs are have the Content Security Policy set using [DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-delegatingrequestmatcherheaderwriter). For example, using Spring Security 4+ you can use:

```xml
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*/yyy/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*/zzz/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/*/api/products" access="xxxx" />


    <headers>
        <header ref="headerWriter"/>
    </headers>

    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- ... -->
</http>

<beans:bean id="headerWriter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher">
             <beans:constructor-arg>

                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher"
            c:pattern="/*/yyy/**"/>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher"
            c:pattern="/*/zzz/**"/>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter"
            c:headerName="Content-Security-Policy"
            c:headerValues="default-src 'self'"  
        />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Note that if you are using Spring Security 3, then you will need to explicitly list all the headers you want enabled (adding any explicit headers means only those headers are applied). For example:

```
    <headers>
        <cache-control />
        <content-type-options />
        <hsts />
        <frame-options />
        <xss-protection />

        <header ref="headerWriter"/>
    </headers>
```

You can find additional details on the differences in [the migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4).

Comment: Rob, thanks for reply. Wouldn't this apply entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" to these two urls as well:<intercept-url pattern="/*/yyy/**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/*/zzz/**" access="permitAll"/>       I do not want these two urls to go through the entry-point-ref

Comment: An AuthenticationEntryPoint is used to handle when authentication is required, but the user has not authenticated yet. If you indicate that anyone (including unauthenticated users) can access the URLs, the AuthenticationEntryPoint will not be used for those URLs

Comment: Rob, Based on my observation, <intercept-url pattern="/*/yyy/**" access="permitAll" />  is taking it to the entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" which I do not want

Comment: What it the actual pattern you are using and the actual URL? Remember that intercept-url elements are considered in order they are specified and only the first is used.

Comment: <http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/*/oidc/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*/authn/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    </http>

Comment: What is the URL you are submitting? Is that the only <http> you specified?